# РУлит или рулИт?

Tags: ударение

Здравствуйте.
ЛюбИть - лЮбит, губИть - гУбит. А рулИть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: РУЛ***И***ТЬ, -л***ю***, -л***и***шь; рул***и***т.